# jquery datepicker only month and year

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I have two problems:

1. Button 'Today' does not work because the calendar is not initialized with the selected value, and initialize the current month.
2. I need override onclick for button 'Done' - how do this?

script:

```
$('.datefield_month').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM, yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM, yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
            }
        });
```

view:

```
<input name = "Month" class = "datefield_month" value="@Model.Month.ToString("Y", Session["culture"] as CultureInfo)" type="text" id ="Month" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html?m=1  discusses how to implement similar. We have used technique in a few projects